# I have this code below and I want the console to display the text

Tags: javascript, angular, underscore.js

I have this code below and I want to use the underscore in order to display the text below...

```
var log = function(contents) {
        if(_.isArray(contents)) {
            _.each(contents, function(e, i, l) {
                log(e);
              $('#result');
                $('#result').append('</br></br>');
            });
        } else {
            $('#result').append(contents);
        }
    };

    var out = [];
    _.each(ty, function(v,k){
    var hold = {};
    hold.o = {
        l: {
        s:{
            t: 'Trying this for first time...'
        }
      }
    };

    out.push(hold);
    });

    Console.log(out.l.s);
```

I want to display the text 'Trying this for the first time...'

Comment: `Console` should be lowercase`console.log(out.l.s);`

Comment: `out` is an array. Do `console.log(out)`.

Comment: just tried that but does not work

Comment: That means something goes wrong inside the `push` function. You should check if the values are really pushed into the `array`

Comment: how should i do that

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `out.l.s` on an `array`. `out` is an array, so in order to print all the text you have to iterate over the array

Replace:

```
Console.log(out.l.s);
```

With:

```
_.each(out, function(item) { 
    console.log(item.o.l.s.t)
});
```

You could just log the array like this:

```
console.log(out)
```

But that will print the entire array structure with all the objects in it, and not just the text

Comment: It should work, can you provide an example jsfiddle or the error you see?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sbv1o75f/27/ There you go. You shouldn't have removed the old code. The code I posted should have been appended at the end. There was however one error, it should have been `item.o.l.s.t` instead of `item.o.s.t`. I've changed that in my answer

Comment: mate, thank you very much for the answer it worked but i did not understand well the question because what i want is something similar to this: 

hold.options (tooltips object) = {
 (property based on the section generated automatically): {
  (properly based on the itemName generated automatically): {
       t: item.Texts,       
    }
  } @shotor

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is wrong try `console.log(out);`

Comment: not only that, but also out is an array and not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot for your answer, but actually, what i want is something similar to what is below:

```
hold.options (tooltips object) = {
 (property based on the section generated automatically): {
  (properly based on the itemName generated automatically): {
       t: item.Texts,       
    }
  }
```